# Can %in% be used in base R to match value pairs?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm familiar with %in% generally, and I'm looking for a base R solution, if one exists.

Suppose I want to know whether a particular combination of values from multiple fields in a data frame exists in another data frame. As a work-around, sometimes I concatenate all these values into a single field and match on the custom concatenation, but I'm wondering if there's a way to pass the value combinations to %in% directly.

I'm imagining syntax similar to deduplicating on unique combinations of values across multiple columns, whose syntax works like this, by way of a generic example:

```
df[!duplicated(df[,c("col1","col2","col3")]),]
```

I was sort of expecting something like this to work, but I see why it doesn't:

```
df1[df1[,c("col1","col2")] %in% df2[,c("col1","col2")],]
```

... above, I'm attempting to ask which value pairs in df1 also exist as value pairs in df2.

Comment: No, that shouldn't work, you need to match column by column with `mapply`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `mapply` to create a logical matrix of matches and then use it to subset `df1`.

Test data.

```
set.seed(2022)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = letters[1:10], col2 = 1:10, col3 = 11:20)
df2 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(letters[1:10], 4), 
                  col2 = sample(1:10, 4), col3 = 11:14)
```

Here I start by putting the columns in a vector, it simplifies the code.

```
cols <- c("col1", "col2")
(i <- mapply(\(x, y) x %in% y, df1[cols], df2[cols]))
#       col1  col2
# [1,] FALSE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE FALSE
# [4,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
# [6,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [7,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE  TRUE
#[10,] FALSE FALSE
```

Now subset. The question is not very clear on which of the following is asked for.

```
# at least one column match
j <- rowSums(i) > 0L
df1[j, ]
#  col1 col2 col3
#3    c    3   13
#4    d    4   14
#6    f    6   16
#7    g    7   17
#9    i    9   19

# all columns match
k <- rowSums(i) == length(cols)
df1[k, ]
#  col1 col2 col3
#4    d    4   14
#6    f    6   16
#7    g    7   17
```

Answer (score 1):

I think just doing a `merge()` by the two columns of interest get you what you need. You can then subset the merged output to just columns from the original `data.frame`. This would return only rows of your query `data.frame` where `col1` and `col2` match their cognate values in the reference `data.frame`. Please clarify if that's NOT your goal.

```r
# simulate two DFs with some common values in col1 and col2
x <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[1:5],
                col2 = 1:5,
                col3 = runif(5))

y <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS[4:8],
                col2 = 4:8,
                col3 = runif(5))

x
#>   col1 col2      col3
#> 1    A    1 0.4306611
#> 2    B    2 0.7149893
#> 3    C    3 0.2808990
#> 4    D    4 0.4383580
#> 5    E    5 0.1372991
y
#>   col1 col2       col3
#> 1    D    4 0.40191250
#> 2    E    5 0.94833538
#> 3    F    6 0.85608320
#> 4    G    7 0.05758958
#> 5    H    8 0.29011770

# merge without adding .x suffix to col3 from x
# then subset to only keep columns from x
merge(x, y, 
      by = c("col1", "col2"), 
      suffixes = c("", ".drop"))[,1:ncol(x)]
#>   col1 col2      col3
#> 1    D    4 0.4383580
#> 2    E    5 0.1372991
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>